# Angualr material create mat-table with dynamic column and column with multiple options

Tags: angular, user-interface, angular-material, mat-table

I want to configure dynamic columns with multiple options in column to Mat table

this is my html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataT" class="mat-elevation-z8">
                <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column.name}}" *ngFor="let column of pgCol">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column.title}} </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column.name]}} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="pgCol"></tr>
                <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: pgCol;"></tr>
            </table>
```

this is my data

```
  pgCol= [
      {
        "name": "id",
        "title": "ID",
        "show": false,
        "sort": false,
        "export": false
      },
      {
        "name": "code",
        "title": "Code",
        "show": true,
        "sort": true,
        "export": true
      },
      {
        "name": "name",
        "title": "Name",
        "show": true,
        "sort": true,
        "export": true
      }
    ]
    dataT = [{ "id": 1, "name": "firstbranch", "code": "fifif" },
  { "id": 1, "name": "firstbranch", "code": "fifif" },
  { "id": 1, "name": "firstbranch", "code": "fifif" },
  { "id": 1, "name": "firstbranch", "code": "fifif" },
  { "id": 1, "name": "firstbranch", "code": "fifif" },
  { "id": 1, "name": "firstbranch", "code": "fifif" },
  { "id": 1, "name": "firstbranch", "code": "fifif" },
  { "id": 1, "name": "firstbranch", "code": "fifif" },
  { "id": 1, "name": "firstbranch", "code": "fifif" }];
```

I just want as per data code and name column should display as per property like sort and export

Answer (score 0):

```html
Try this one

In HTML

<mat-table [dataSource]='data' matSort matSortDisableClear [matSortActive]='sortoptions.sortcol' 
 [matSortDirection]='sortoptions.sortdir' (matSortChange)='onSortChange($event)'>  
 
 In ts file
 
 sortoptions = { sortcol: 'columnname', sortdir: 'asc' };
```